# ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1094

Tags: android, multithreading, jsoup

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://some.com/login";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        new asad().execute();
    }

    class asad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Document doc =null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_URL).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("DDD","failcha"); 
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class));
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

}
```

and `exception` in `19 line`:

Why Thread 17 is stopped?

What `ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1094` means?

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Running) 
    Thread [<10> Binder Thread #2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder Thread #1] (Running) 
    Daemon Thread [<8> FinalizerWatchdogDaemon] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [<7> FinalizerDaemon] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [<6> ReferenceQueueDaemon] (Running)  
    Thread [<14> CookieSyncManager] (Running)   
    Thread [<12> WebViewCoreThread] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [<11> SCHTimer] (Running) 
    Thread [<15> AsyncTask #1] (Running)    
    Thread [<13> Binder Thread #3] (Running)    
    Thread [<16> Thread-6910] (Running) 
    Thread [<17> AsyncTask #2] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1094  
        ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 569   
        Thread.run() line: 856  
    Thread [<18> AsyncTask #3] (Running)
```

last line on Logcat:

```
 I/GATE(2586): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
```

I used [Jsoup library](http://jsoup.org)

Comment: You are going to need to provide more context and information.  Maybe some small code samples?

Comment: Looks to me that the `AsyncTask` threw a `RuntimeException` of course.  I'd consider wrapping your methods in some `try { } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }` or something to spit out what the exception is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheers, well done!

I added Jsoup.jar to the libs folder and removed from `Java Build path->libraries`;